# Question about the 0 eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Suppose I have a linear transformation T: V to V, and I know that $Tx=0, x\neq0$ (not injective). Then can I say that $0$ is an eigenvalue of T because $Tx=0x$? I am thinking yes because since $x\neq0$ and $0x = 0$ and I can induce an x. Am I correct or missing something?

Comment: Yes, zero is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if $T$ is not injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right! And null space is zero eigenspace of that matrix.